# Is there a way to calculate big O complexity for this non-binary tree algorithm?

Tags: recursion, big-o, binary-search-tree, complexity-theory

I have implemented a data-structure that is kind of a non-binary tree and my algorithm basically goes through all of it's branches (I will provide more details on how it works below).

So, for a base case of a mother-node with three children the data structure would look something like this:

[image: Simple tree picture]

And the algorithm would go through three interactions until it eventually stopped (the function that goes through each node is recursive and the recursion stops when it finds a node that has no children/no nodes below it):

[image: Interactions on base case]

So, in a second case scenario, if the the tree was a little more complex, something like this:

[image: Second case's tree]

Obs: In the case above, more than one parent node is arriving at the same child node, but this second interaction/arriving at the same child node through a different parent node is necessary, since it could add additional information/features to the child node and thus cannot be skipped.

And the algorithm would run through seven interactions in this second case:

[image: Interactions on second case]

So, basically, the algorithm enters in a for loop every time it needs to access the sons of a node. In case two, for example, there's a first for that access nodes 2, 3 and 4 from node 1 and then a second for the access nodes 5 and 6 from node 2. When all nodes below node 2 have already been accessed, and since nodes 5 and 6 do not have child-nodes, the for from node 1 access node 3 and then a third for begins, which access node 6 from node 3. Finally, when all nodes below node 3 have already been accessed, the for loop from node 1 will access node 4 and a fourth for loop begins, which eventually access node 7 and then the algorithm as a whole stops.

In addition to the complexity of the algorithm I would also like to know if something like this could run in a web application or would it be too slow or too complex to run in a server? I don't know, it seems to me that the computational cost is too high and either running this in a large scale would fry my PC or it would eventually run but after a considerable amount of time.

I hope that I was able to explain the problem I'm dealing with, but if more information is needed, do not hesitate to ask me in the comments. Thanks to all of you for your attention in advance.

Comment: That is not a tree, the algorithm appears to be O(n) where n is the number of edges, and whether it would be too slow to run on a server (or any other platform) depends on how many edges are in the graph and how long each step takes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Just out of curiosity, is there a name for a structure like this? A tree where nodes can have more than one parent node?

Comment: It looks like a directed acyclic graph (DAG). That is, a graph (a set of nodes with edges between some of them) which is directional (if two nodes are connected by an edge, one node is the parent and the other is the child), and which contains no cycle (if you start at one node, then step to that node's child, then step to *that* node's child, and so on, you can  never arrive back at the first node). It is not a tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I was struggling with this for quite some time. Can I refine my original question a bit? At each node actually a query is needed in order to identify which children nodes are entitled to continue the algorithm and which are not. So, for example, imagine that node 2 had three children, but only node 5 and 6 had a certain value in a certain column that allowed them to continue in the algorithm. Does this "check" to select the children invalidate the O(n) hypothesis or is it not unreasonable to assume the same execution time for all queries executed by the nodes?

Comment: What if node 6 (in your example) would have a child: would that child be visited twice because of the two different paths to node 6, or would the second path (via interaction #5) stop at 6 and not continue to its child? The additional specification of conditions is too vague. The complexity depends on such factors, but they need to be specified. The effect of one condition on the complexity is not the same as another. So make this question as concrete as possible.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up @trincot , I should have pointed this right in the beginning and I sincerely apologize for not having done this. Yes, the algorithm would go to the child of node 6 twice. It visits the nodes at all the possible paths that it can. So I do not think the complexity is O(n), but I know it's my fault not bringing this point since the beginning of the post.

Comment: Then indeed O(n) is not possible. In a dense graph (with lots of edges coming into a single node), not only nodes, but also edges will be visited multiple times. And the longer the paths are, the more revisits there are, so it could be exponential in terms of the average path length.